# Spark - Reading CSV file with HEADER and TRAIL rows... how to ignore them?

Tags: apache-spark

Is there any way to ignore the last row on each file as the same using skip=1 for the header?
Running multiple files at once.

Comment: You can add `zipWithIndex` and filter the rows that you don't want.

Comment: use `mode=DROPMALFORMED`...?

Comment: I believe mode=DROPMALFORMED will do the trick.. thanks a lot! Will post reply after test it.